# in calcite how to modify the generated SQLNode with another sqlNode?

Tags: java, sql, apache-calcite

If I have a SqlNode *node* parsed from the sql

```
select id, age from student where id > 5
```

, and I also have another SqlNode *subNode* parsed from another subcondition

```
id < 20
```

Then, how to merge this two so that I can get a SqlNode have the same result parsed from the sql

```
select id, age from student where id > 5 and id < 20
```

Can I append the subNode to the *where* property of SqlSelect in *node*? May be I can append the subcondition at first, but in a more complex circumstance, this will be very difficult by use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `AND` operator, you can use `SqlUtil.andExpressions` to combine two conditions, as follows:

```
SqlUtil.andExpressions(con1, con2);
```

Also, you can use the `SqlStdOperatorTable.AND` to build a `AND` expression:

```
// list contains the operators, such as id > 5 and id < 20
SqlStdOperatorTable.AND.createCall(SqlParserPos.ZERO, list)
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases, it solves well. However, for a more complicated case, if there are nested query and the condition should place at the correct position, we should traversal the basic `SqlNode` and append the extra condition to the correct place.

Create a class extends [`SqlBasicVisitor`](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/sql/util/SqlBasicVisitor.java), override the `visit` method to do this, mainly the part of `visit(SqlCall call)` and `visit(SqlNodeList nodeList)`should be override.